# SQL script works in 'posgres' schema, but not in other?

Tags: postgresql, dump, psql

I am trying to dump an old database back into my system, but a weird error occurs.
When I login to 'postgres' database (psql posgtgres) the files would load, and the data would be also inserted,

```
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
```

but when I login to the database I created(psql EXAMPLE), it says

```
syntax error near "1"
```

Here is the part of the file that fails when I'm logged in to 'EXAMPLE' database :

```
 ...f92, f93, f94) FROM stdin;
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Please note that it is exactly the same file, and it was not edited before I connected to 'EXAMPLE' database.
Thank you in advance

EDIT:

Here is the copy command that gives the error.

```
COPY mmm_a1_0912_vorskla_02c (shot_num, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14, f15, f16, f17, f18, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f24, f25, f26, f27, f28, f29, f30, f31, f32, f33, f34, f35, f36, f37, f38, f39, f40, f41, f42, f43, f44, f45, f46, f47, f48, f49, f50, f51, f52, f53, f54, f55, f56, f57, f58, f59, f60, f61, f62, f63, f64, f65, f66, f67, f68, f69, f70, f71, f72, f73, f74, f75, f76, f77, f78, f79, f80, f81, f82, f83, f84, f85, f86, f87, f88, f89, f90, f91, f92, f93, f94) FROM stdin;
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

**EDIT#2**

FIXED:

Actually I initially assumed that every database you create will have a 'public' schema by default. My newly created database didn't. That was the issue.

Comment: Please show the exact commands you use, not just parts of them.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen , here is the edit + one line of input

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you reading from a file or from standard input? Are your columns boolean/integer data type?

Comment: @ConsiderMe I found the problem. Please see the last post edit